# Hiding UITableView Under Navigation Bar

Tags: ios

I have a custom view for the Navigation Bar which displays title and subtitle. When I scroll I hide the NavigationBar using the "Hides Bar on Swipe" property.

Unfortunately, my UITableView still extends to the full screen as shown below: 
[image]

I played around with different properties on UINavigationController in Storyboard

```
Under Top Bars - unchecked  
Under Bottom Bars - unchecked
```

UINavigationController Storyboard Settings:

[image]

MyTableViewController Storyboard Settings:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to set status bar view background as white.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove tick mark on a show navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and expected behavior. This is exactly why you should *not* hide the navigation bar; you need it to provide a cover for your table view on “notched” devices.

Comment: You will notice that all of Apple’s own apps using table or collection views always have the navigation bar in portrait orientation, for this very reason.

Comment: glich is in hiding nav bar not in orientation.

Comment: I am using Apple News app as a model and Apple News app hides the navigation bar.

Comment: Okay good example. But in that case an extra view is inserted behind the status bar / notch to cover the top of the scroll view.  And there was never any nav bar at all! So you need to pick a model here.